# Why aren't raw transactions showing up on Etherscan?

Tags: transactions, ethereum

I am creating and sending raw transactions by starting a Geth node locally and using these commands:

> tx = eth.signTransaction({ from: "0x2efd0bf3afb26cfdcb3bed5e6c701a84b7b5f200", to: "0x22d2eb37c7aa972420c5e3f43c1fd808602c74e1",value: web3.toWei(0.0005, "ether"), gas: 21000, gasPrice:30000000000, nonce: 0});

{
  raw: "0xf86b808506fc23ac008252089422d2eb37c7aa972420c5e3f43c1fd808602c74e18701c6bf52634000801ba07f3ecb56dafe03a88c2053d3ffa3a81f3717a68b1f76e62eed3e196b8bf69e4ba01dc6df2f67ad4eb3a01f401d8b45367a917b8b7e7c2dcb8933ccce5a482a7115",
  tx: {
    gas: "0x5208",
    gasPrice: "0x6fc23ac00",
    hash: "0xe7d97a52f6396b2e344ecd363b41c600165c81481f9fc482356ac1f3e13d0146",
    input: "0x",
    nonce: "0x0",
    r: "0x7f3ecb56dafe03a88c2053d3ffa3a81f3717a68b1f76e62eed3e196b8bf69e4b",
    s: "0x1dc6df2f67ad4eb3a01f401d8b45367a917b8b7e7c2dcb8933ccce5a482a7115",
    to: "0x22d2eb37c7aa972420c5e3f43c1fd808602c74e1",
    v: "0x1b",
    value: "0x1c6bf52634000"
  }

> eth.sendRawTransaction(tx.raw)

I am sure that I have correct addresses and nonce value. However, when I check etherscan, the transaction does not show up, even after many hours. The geth node is not fully synced but this should be fine since I am sending raw transactions and getting a successfully returned hash. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Could it be that my node is not connected to enough peers?

Comment: the root cause is your node is not synced with mainnet. so your call will not broadcast to everyone.

Comment: Why won't it broadcast to everyone?

Comment: the node should be synced with mainnet, then the node can submit tx to another node.

Comment: Why does the node need to be synced in order to submit a tx to another node? Shouldn't you be able to send a raw transaction without being synced?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Eliza's Question, let me have some time to try answer the internal caused reason.

1. Why does the node need to be synced in order to submit a tx to another node?
2. Answer: it should be broadcast but not sure mined or send. firstly check local node status: eth.pendingTransactions, many more case with your issue is caused by nonce or gas price.

Shouldn't you be able to send a raw transaction without being synced?
2. Answer: if your node is not syncd , you can't correctly get correct address's nonce or currently normal gas price.So i suggest you get a synced node in fast mode or full mode is best options.